# remote pc>mapped drives to txt

Tags: batch-file, dictionary, wmic, drives

my intent is to get this..

```
cls
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
echo Create backup txt file of mapped drives
echo -----
set /p PCname=Asset tag or IP address:
set /p UserID=UserID:
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in (
'wmic netuse get LocalName^, RemoteName^, Status /format:list ^| find ":"'
) do echo(%%a %%b>> \\%PCname%\c$\windows\temp\%PCname%_%UserID%_map.txt
xcopy /d/y \\%PCname%\c$\windows\temp\%PCname%_%UserID%_map.txt ".\remoteStats\"
pause
Goto :mdmenu
```

to map drives of a remote pc,`%PCname%`,to a text file with just the drive letter and path, copy that text file to the techs computer running the script into a .\remotestats\ folder

this way I can use that same text file to remap those drives automatically

```
:mdrestore
cls
echo Map Drives from backup txt
echo -----
echo Notes:
echo Needs a backup to restore from, inside
echo remoteStats folder
echo. 
set /p PCname=Asset tag or IP address:
set /p UserID=Enter BH Username:
for /f %%a in (.\RemoteStats\%PCname%_%username%_map.txt) do Psexec \\%PCname% -d -s cmd /c net use %%a /p:Yes
psexec \\%PCname% -d cmd.exe /c net use S: \\mapped.drive\share /p:Yes
psexec \\%PCname% -d cmd.exe /c net use H: \\mappeddrive2\home  /p:Yes
Print "Drives mapped"
Timeout /t 30 >nul
GOTO :mdmenu
```

Comment: "guess my problem"?

Comment: might work better with `/format:csv` in the first script and `"delims="` in the second one.

Comment: THe first batch should have `format:csv` instead of list. Otherwise it's totally unclear to me what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @LotPings, fixed the csv issue. but now the issue is getting it to work remotely. currently I run it from PC '1' and it just saves a file with the userid and pcname provided, doesnt actually run anything on PC '2' aka whatever is designated as %pcname%

Comment: @Stephan 
Got it to work remotely.. 

`echo Create backup txt file of mapped drives
echo -----
 set /p PCname=Asset tag or IP address:
 set /p UserID=Enter BH Username:
     for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%a in (
        'psexec \\lw410330 wmic netuse get LocalName^, RemoteName^, Status /format:csv ^| find ":"'
    ) do echo %%a %%b>> \\%PCname%\c$\windows\temp\%PCname%_%UserID%_map.txt
 xcopy /d/y \\%PCname%\c$\windows\temp\%PCname%_%UserID%_map.txt "c:\BruticusReports\remoteStats\"
echo Drives Backed up to RemoteStats Folder
Timeout /t 3 >nul
GOTO :mdmenu`

Comment: Now just trying to get the restore option working..
`:mdrestore
cls
echo Map Drives from backup txt
echo -----
echo Notes:
echo Needs a backup to restore from, inside
echo remoteStats folder
echo. 
set /p PCname=Asset tag or IP address:
set /p UserID=Enter BH Username:
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (c:\BruticusReports\RemoteStats\%PCname%_%UserID%_map.txt) do psexec \\%PCname% net use %%a /p:Yes 
echo "Drives restored"
Timeout /t 15 >nul`